# Best place to store non model/non controller code in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, coding-style

So I was reading a blog entry from [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) which has a nice piece of code for crating a new validation object in MVC3

[image: Code Snippet From Scott Gu's Blog]

Where "logically" is the best place to store this in a MVC3 environment? Is it best to store it in a new project linked to the solution? Is there a app_code equivalent folder in MVC as there is in Webforms?

I like to keep everything neat and tidy when coding (possible OCD!) but want to pick best practises amongst the community.

Comment: The "best practice" for this is not specific to the MVC pattern.  Store it where it makes sense to do so, using ordinary organizational techniques.

Comment: @SLaks Not my regex ;) Just lifted from Scott Gu's blog, but not really disputing that part right now, just trying to work out the best place to put the code, I'm going to be writing a lot more validators.

Comment: It's a "close enough" regex; it's not meant to be comprehensive or 100% correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure code like this could be reused in a variety of projects, and isn't specific to the web application that I'm working on. So I create a special utilities project, and inside that project I may have a namespace for Annotations or Validation or something like that where I'd put a class like this.

Answer (score 1):

I generally separate the solution into at least two assemblies (or projects). One that hosts the actual web application and one that contains business objects, utility classes and methods, etc. This helps generally also when you need to reuse some of that logic in separate locations - for example, let's say that you end up writing a Windows service that needs some of that logic and those business objects, it helps if they are isolated in their own assembly. The web project namespace is reserved only for presentation-related stuff rather than business functionality. In a way I suppose I always consider the ASP or WinForms or MVC side to be just a conduit to the actual meat of the application in the business assembly. So that's where I would probably end up putting something like this.